# Unconditional inference in the multinomial model

Tags: bayesian, categorical-data, binomial-distribution, multinomial-distribution

Consider a multinomial $2\times 2$ table $\begin{pmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} \\ x_{21} & x_{22} \end{pmatrix}$ with theoretical probabilities: $$\begin{pmatrix} \theta_{11} & \theta_{12} \\  \theta_{21} & \theta_{22} \end{pmatrix}.$$ 
The conditional distribution of $x_{11}$ given $x_{11}+x_{12}=n$ is binomial with size $n$ and proportion $p=\dfrac{\theta_{11}}{\theta_{11}+\theta_{12}}$. Therefore we have a straightforward way to perform statistical inference on $p$ by conditioning on $x_{11}+x_{12}$. Is it possible to do an unconditional inference on $p$ ?

Parenthesis : I have noted that adopting the Bayesian approach with the Jeffreys (Dirichlet) prior of the unconditional multinomial model is equivalent to adopt the Bayesian approach with the Jeffreys (Beta) prior of the conditional binomial model.

Comment: How are the elements in the table sampled? If $x_{11}+x_{12}=n$ is fixed by design, the conditional inference is natural. If you just sample $x_{11}+x_{12}+x_{21}+x_{22}$ observations and collect their corresponding row/column variables, unconditional inference on $p$ may be obtained using a multinomial model.

Comment: Exactly - in my case only the total sum of the table is fixed by design, and my question is about the way to perform inference on $p$ using the "unconditional" multinomial model (I hope this will yield a smaller confidence interval)

Comment: Then yes, you can do unconditional inference; it's perhaps easiest to parameterize in terms of $p=\frac{\theta_{11}}{\theta_{11}+\theta_{12}}, q=\frac{\theta_{21}}{\theta_{21}+\theta_{22}}$ and $\psi=\frac{\theta_{11}\theta_{22}}{\theta_{12}\theta_{21}}$; use standard MLE arguments on $logit(p)$. But don't expect much efficiency gain; under particular assumptions, conditioning on _both_ $x_{11}+x_{12}$ and $x_{11}+x_{21}$ (and $n$) is known to give optimal inference.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know a reference showing this optimality ?